# Https Form Data Visible

Tags: forms, https

I have a question wrt to HTTPS form submission. One of our website is using HTTPS , we display the login page to the user via HTTPS protocol. When the form is submitted, we try to intercept the request using a tool called "Burp Suit" before sending it to the server, I see that the form Data is not encrypted. Is this the right behavior?? Or is it something like the request is  being secured only in transmission over the network??

Thanks